# Is there any reply to Bcc in Email

Tags: php, email

I am working on a Project which is using customer inquiry tracking.

Is there any trick like Bcc reply ?
How to hide another reply email like Bcc

Suppose

Customer email is ( alen@gmail.com )

Admin have two email id

1. His personal email id ( joe@gmail.com )
2. at my project ( joe@myproject.com )

Flow is :

A customer makes a inquiry, email goes to admin's 2nd email account( joe@myproject.com ).

Then admin replies to customer email ( alen@gmail.com ) from admin's 2nd email account ( joe@myproject.com ).

Customer receives email from admin,

Then Customer could reply to admin's 1st email account ( joe@gmail.com ) and 2nd email account ( joe@myproject.com ).

But the admin's 2nd email account ( joe@myproject.com ) should be hide and should not visible to customer.

Is there any trick like Bcc reply ?
Or any other suggestion are welcome. :)

Comment: The client cannot send a reply to an address which is not known to them.

Comment: If you have a contact form, you can send it To/Bcc whoever you like. Or you could set up an email address that forwards it onto other people - Exim has options to set this up, I think. Or if you are using `gmail.com` as the public email domain, maybe that has options for reforwarding.

Comment: @halfer I know i can setup as you guide but requirement is customer will reply to admin personal account and mail should goes to admin 2nd address like Bcc does..

Comment: But my solution will do that. If you are asking how to get the Bcc to come from the customer without them knowing about it, thankfully it is not possible.

Comment: `Bcc:` is not a trick. It is a useful feature that was implemented with serious goals in mind (archiving, for example).

Comment: Set up an email alias which will forward to both admin accounts. Make sure the "admins" set their reply-to address to that of the alias.

Comment: This post has serious formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

The admin can configure their email client to set their 1st email address in the `Reply-To:` field of the emails they send.

Or, if the 1st email address is the personal admin's email address, he/she should not use it for business purposes. Most of the email client programs nowadays can read emails from many accounts and they allow different configuration (name, email, SMTP server etc) for each account. Not mixing business with personal email is not that difficult.

Comment: i agree with your solution.. it was in my mind.. but its last option to me.. ) thanx